# In Civilization 5 the game wants me to adopt a policy but no policies are available?

Tags: civilization-5

What do I do? I've tried right clicking. I just don't know what to do, the game will not let me move on without adopting a policy. This is very agitating. Someone please help.

Answer (score 4):

See this link: http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=415703

> The only way I know how to get around this is to check off the policy saving option before the game starts. I do this and then play as if I hadn't (but know that I'm safe from getting stuck like this.)

or

> I found the only thing that sometimes helps is going to the unit selection and pressing left or right (the box on the left that cycles units). Sometimes...and actually now that I think about it, more times than not, it will cycle to "end turn" and get you out of the lock.

Comment: If "check off" means "check in", what does "check on" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I thought I had done everything i could but i over looked the obvious. ((hits forehead)) The first time you adopt a social policy you don't actually adopt any policies, you just chose the cultural mind set you want to follow out of the 3 available (Tradition, Liberty or Honer) then on the next time you can chose which of the policies of that cultural mindset you would like to put into practice by choosing one of the now colored tiles on the card you chose in the last turn or you can chose another cultural path instead.  Also there seem to be a link in the game between culture points and fast you can inaciate a new policy.

So my advice is not to turn off the policy saving option because you want to chose and save every time you get the opportunity.

Comment: I believe sean is asking what to do when no additional policy is available, i.e. when all possible policy trees have not only been revealed but have actually been fully "bought".