# How Can I Stop Game From Stopping After 3 or 4 Social Policies?

Tags: civilization-5

I get the icon saying adopt a policy and I do, but after I adopt the first 3 or 4 that are unlocked, the game will not progress and I'm stuck where I am. No more turns, no more production.

I am new to the game and being there is no real manual to consult, I am at a loss.

Do I have to adopt a Social Policy when icon appears or can I ignore until later in game?

Comment: Whether you have to adopt a social policy immediately or not depends on the version of Civ5 you are running, as well as possibly an option that can be set per game.  However, I'm a bit confused - are you unable to pick a social policy?

Comment: When you say "the game will not progress", what is it actually doing? What does the right-hand corner say? Is it asking you to choose another policy, and none are available?

Comment: I can pick social policies up to Piety, and, when icon appears in lower right telling me I "May" adopt one, it is a must, as it will not disappear or allow the next turn to progress until I do. It's fine until I reach Piety, and then, the rest are still locked and it stalls there, not permitting turns or progress. I am using Civ5, The Complete Edition. If there is an option to pre set prior to beginning, can anyone tell me where it is in menus, as I thought I had looked to do just that.

Comment: @MKeith - If you unlock Piety, you should then be able to choose under Piety either Organized Religion or Mandate of Heaven, which then unlocks other options further down the tree.  Each category pane should work in the same way.  If its actually not, maybe you should add a screenshot to your question, so we can see if this is just miscommunication or if your game is actually bugging out.

Answer (score 6):

On default settings, you have to pick a social policy whenever you earn one.

That said, there ought to be plenty to choose from, unless your game has done something odd.  You said the first 3 or 4 are unlocked, but unless I'm mistaken those are only categories; you can select more specific policies inside those categories as well.

See also [In Civilization 5 the game wants me to adopt a policy but no policies are available?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77559/in-civilization-5-the-game-wants-me-to-adopt-a-policy-but-no-policies-are-availa?rq=1) and if you find the option to there is also [How do I stockpile policies in games with 'enable policy saving' on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103636/how-do-i-stockpile-policies-in-games-with-enable-policy-saving-on?rq=1)

Comment: Each of those cards are policy *trees*: Tradition, Honor, Piety, etc. It costs one point to unlock each tree, gaining some benefits, which makes five more policies within that tree available with future points. Hover over each tree to see the policies contained within and their benefits. You also gain additional benefits once you've chosen every policy within a tree.